# Scheme: Beta-Reduction Challenge

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket, lambda-calculus

My teacher has given the class some sample exam questions (the class is basically on Scheme (Racket) and the lambda calculus), and I've hit a wall with the following problem:

> Define `(β-reduce e)` such that, when a β-reduction is possible (i.e., when `e` is of the form `((λ v e1) e2)` and there are no free variable conflicts that block the β-reduction and would require some α-renaming first), it returns the result of the β-reduction. Otherwise, it returns `#f`.

Example:

```
(β-reduce '((λ x (((λ x (x y)) x) (x b))) z)) ⇒ (((λ x (x y)) z) (z b))
(β-reduce '((λ x (((λ y (x y)) x) (x b))) y)) ⇒ #f
```

I haven't gotten very far (to say the least). I started thinking that I should look for something in the form `((λ x (x)) y)` as that's when I'll need to do a beta reduction, but I'm getting stuck on how to replace the inner expression with `y` and then recurse inside of it if there were more sub expressions. Also, I'm really not sure when I would return `#f`.

Here's what I've got:

```
(define beta-reduce 
  (lambda (e)
    (cond 
      ((and (equal? 'lambda (caar e)) (symbol? (last e))) 
       replace inner bound variable and recurse ))))
```

If anyone could help me get to the bottom of this, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer but an attempt to get you started.

You need to consider arbitrary expressions for `e1` and `e2` in `((λ v e1) e2)`.

Another example:

```
(β-reduce '((λ x (x x)) (λ y y)) ⇒ ((λ y y) (λ y y))
```

Don't try to write the entire thing as one big function, break the problem down into manageable pieces.
You'll probably want the following:

- A different way of determining that your expression is a function application.
- A function `free-variables` that takes an expression and returns the names that occur free in the expression.
- A function `substitute-variable` that takes a variable `v`, an expression `E1`, and an expression `E2`, and replaces all free occurences of `v` in `E1` with `E2`.

The substition is possible if the intersection of `(free-variables '(λ v E1))` and `(free-variables E2)` is empty.

If your course has a reasonable structure, you've already written these functions, or something very similar to them.

And remember that the reduction only takes one "step" - you should only reduce the outermost application, as shown by the first example you were given.